# How can I pass a new array to a function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, parameters

This is bad practice, I know. It's just for testing, but I can't seem to get it to work. Can I pass a new, initialized array to a JavaScript function?

I'm looking for the JavaScript equivalent of this C# method:

```
public void MyFunction(new string[]{"1","2","3"})
{    
}
```

I tried this, but to no avail:

```
function MyFunction(new array ('1','2','3')) {    
}
```

Comment: it's `new Array()` with a capital A.

Comment: You (dmck) added JavaScript to the title? I thought we weren't supposed to do that since we use tags.

Comment: @katspaugh "Restore true justice." Hilarious, dude.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's easier than that:

```
  function myFunction( arr ) { ... }
```

Then:

```
  myFunction([1, 2, 3, "hello"]);
```

In function **declarations** there is no type information necessary (or possible).  Just list out the parameter names.  Then, when you call the function, you can use the array literal notation (just like you can in any expression to instantiate an array).

Comment: Ah, it took me far too long to spot my mistake. *Sigh...*

Comment: Yeah, but I failed to differentiate between function-creation, and function-calling. Which I really should've spotted.